# How to use a jQuery tooltip in a Google Chrome Extension's content script?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, jquery-tooltip

I want to have a tooltip for certain elements on all those web pages which are affected by my chrome extension. The jQuery UI provides tooltip functionalities but I am not able to use them into a content script.

1. What changes would I need to make to the manifest.json file?
2. How to get the $('tag').tooltip() working?

PS : Initial research from my end says that using jQuery in a normal web-page-JS tie-up is different from using jQuery tooltip in a chrome extension.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For sure you can !

Add this on your manifest :

```
"content_scripts": 
[ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "css": ["css/xxx.css"],
      "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/xxx.js"],
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
} ],
```

Then you can use jQuery like if it was a normal web page using your content-script ;)

Comment: Thanks for this. Seems to be working fine for HTML pages, but I have another issue. I want it to work for XML pages also. Any help on XML pages?? :)